# Promoting the affected file to remote server

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I work on web app.

The file in my development environment that contains changes are pushed to perforce.
In order to deploy the development changes to qa server, I used to manually copy the affected files(perforce commits) from development server to qa server.

Now, I am planning to use Jenkins. I am using Jenkins plugin to hook up perforce changes.  Whenever Jenkins build is triggered, all the perforce changes are detected by Jenkins job. As soon as the build runs, I want to run a shell script that copies the affected files of perforce to qa server.

I went through the docs, but there is no way to fetch the affected files of the build.

Can you recommend me the way to copy the affected files of build to qa server?

Comment: Are you looking for 'p4 sync'?

Comment: No P4 sync. I was looking for a way to copy affected files in perforce, to qa server, by simple unix copy command, not by triggering p4 sync on qa server.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Perforce replication at all? Perhaps a 'Build Farm' or 'On-Demand' type replica server would suit your needs and would thus copy the changes over for you.

Otherwise, on a Unix OS a command like 'rsync' can be used to copy files from one location to another.

REFERENCES

Admin Guide - Perforce Replication
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4dist/chapter.replication.html

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/On-Demand-Replication